# Google Vision API not working Grpc.Core.RpcException

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, google-api, environment-variables

I'm trying to get Google Vision API to work with my project but having trouble. I keep getting the following error:

Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=PermissionDenied, Detail="This API method requires billing to be enabled

I've created a service account, billing is enabled and I have the .json file. I've got the Environment variable for my account for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS pointing to the .json file.

I've yet to find a solution to my problem using Google documentation or checking StackOverFlow.

```
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Vision
{
    internal static class GoogleVision
    {
        public static EntityAnnotation[] GetAnnotations(EventManager em, string filePath, string EventNr)
        {
            {
                ImageAnnotatorClient Client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
                Image Image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromFile(filePath);
                IReadOnlyList<EntityAnnotation> Response = Client.DetectLabels(Image);

                EntityAnnotation[] annotations = new EntityAnnotation[Response.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < annotations.Length; i++)
                {
                    annotations[i] = Response[i];
                }

                return annotations;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but by setting the environment variable in the code rather than manually with windows, it fixed the problem.

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "thejsonfile");
```